# Htaccess rewrite urls with specific ending

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite all urls with ending `id=111` (For example, `www.mysite.com/1/id=111` , `www.mysite.com/page_id=1?id=111` and so on) to `www.mysite.com/pages`. How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

$if the URL ends with id=111
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} id=111\  [NC]  
#then rewrite the request to pages
RewriteRule ^ pages [L]
```

If you want to change the URL in the users address bar to `www.mysite.com/pages` then change the last rule above to include a `R=301` as below

```
#then redirect the request to pages
RewriteRule ^ pages? [L,R=301]
```